# How to create a theme for a GWT application?

Tags: gwt

I want to create a user selectable theme to a GWT application? How can I do It?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use CSS to build theme-system on top of GWT. There are DOM structures in GWT components that limit the options what can be themed, but in general CSS (and CSS3 these days) is very powerful and designed just for this kind of things.

Simply, you can put single theme in a single CSS file and provide users with an option to change the effective CSS file.

Here you can find discussion about creating such system: http://groups.google.com/group/google-web-toolkit/browse_thread/thread/f4b8f184c49b98f9